# Python email.header.decode_header fails for multiline headers

Tags: python, email

I'm building a system that reads emails from a gmail account and fetches the subjects, using Python's `imaplib` and `email` modules. Sometimes, emails received from a hotmail account have line breaks in their headers, for instance:

```
In [4]: message['From']
Out[4]: '=?utf-8?B?aXNhYmVsIG1hcsOtYSB0b2Npbm8gZ2FyY8OtYQ==?=\r\n\t<isatocino22@hotmail.com>'
```

If I try to decode that header, it does nothing:

```
In [5]: email.header.decode_header(message['From'])
Out[5]: [('=?utf-8?B?aXNhYmVsIG1hcsOtYSB0b2Npbm8gZ2FyY8OtYQ==?=\r\n\t<isatocino22@hotmail.com>', None)]
```

However, if I replace the line break and tab with a space, it works:

```
In [6]: email.header.decode_header(message['From'].replace('\r\n\t', ' '))
Out[6]: [('isabel mar\xc3\xada tocino garc\xc3\xada', 'utf-8'), ('<isatocino22@hotmail.com>', None)]
```

Is this a bug in `decode_header`? If not, I would like to know what other *special cases* like this I should be aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in `decode_header`, which bug is present in python2.7 and fixed in python3.3.

```
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=3, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> email.header.decode_header('=?utf-8?B?aXNhYmVsIG1hcsOtYSB0b2Npbm8gZ2FyY8OtYQ==?=\r\n\t<isatocino22@hotmail.com>')
[(b'isabel mar\xc3\xada tocino garc\xc3\xada', 'utf-8'), (b'<isatocino22@hotmail.com>', None)]
```

*vs*

```
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> email.header.decode_header('=?utf-8?B?aXNhYmVsIG1hcsOtYSB0b2Npbm8gZ2FyY8OtYQ==?=\r\n\t<isatocino22@hotmail.com>')
[('=?utf-8?B?aXNhYmVsIG1hcsOtYSB0b2Npbm8gZ2FyY8OtYQ==?=\r\n\t<isatocino22@hotmail.com>', None)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Are they working on fixing it for the 2.7 branch? I hope so!

Comment: so, what's the solution for Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

This error is still happening in some Python 2.7 versions, so the following workaround could be used:

```
>>> email.header.decode_header('=?utf-8?B?aXNhYmVsIG1hcsOtYSB0b2Npbm8gZ2FyY8OtYQ==?=\r\n\t<isatocino22@hotmail.com>'.replace('\r\n\t', ' '))
[('isabel mar\xc3\xada tocino garc\xc3\xada', 'utf-8'), ('<isatocino22@hotmail.com>', None)]
```

It replaces the CLRF and the tab feed for a whitespace. With this, decode_header will parse correctly the header.